# Ansible - Update env variables during playbook execution

Tags: bash, ansible, environment-variables

I want to update an environment variable on the host (this playbook is executed locally) during the ansible playbook execution, so the remaining tasks can use the updated value of the env variable but it seems that this is not possible.

Let me give you an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
# Environment variable before changing
- set_fact: env_before="{{ lookup('env', 'ENV_VAR') }}"

# A task that updates the env variable, I tried to make the needed configuration
# into ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, /etc/environment

# Environment variable after changing
- set_fact: env_after="{{ lookup('env', 'ENV_VAR') }}"

# Unfortunately env_after = env_before
```

If I re-execute the playbook, but this time not changing the env variable, the **env_before** and **env_after** will have the **updated value of the env variable**.

Example:

```
- 1st Execution:
 - env_before = ENV_VAR = 10
 - update_ENV_VAR to 20 and update ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, /etc/environment files
   with export ENV_VAR=20 etc.
 - env_after = ENV_VAR = 20

- 2nd Execution (Do not make any changes just skip the update_ENV_var step
 - env_before = ENV_VAR = 20 (new value from previous execution)
```

So as of my understanding, ansible is loading env variables only on the start of the playbook, and keeps these values until the end. And it seems that the ansible tasks are not updating/sourcing the corresponding bash conf file. So I cannot find a way to update an ENV variable which its new value will be available in the following task.

The only way this may work is to define **environment:** keyword in the next task, but I want to avoid this. This new value will be used by many tasks, so I'm searching a way to update its value once during playbook execution.

Comment: Why do you use environment variables here and not facts? In general, you can't change environment of a running process in linux in runtime.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I'm using and modifying environment variables because the next task, after the update, is using linux environment variables variables for its execution. But I don't want to use environment keyword per task, so I'm searching for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to change the environment presented to tasks is to use the `environment` keyword on a task or on a play.  If you are using `shell:` tasks you could explicitly source your `~/.bashrc`, etc, but that isn't very pretty.

What if you split your playbook into multiple plays, and set the `environment` key on the play after you've derived its value?  Something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        myvar: "some value"

- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    MYVAR: "{{ myvar }}"
  tasks:
    - shell: "echo $MYVAR"
      register: res

    - debug:
        msg: "MYVAR = {{ res.stdout }}"
```

This would modify the environment for all tasks in the second play.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good advice and workaround. Not really what I wanted, but I'll look into it. Sourcing of ~/.bashrc will actually update the env variables for this task? The next task (if is not using source ~/.bashrc) will have the "old" one, right?

Comment: Well, sourcing `~/.bashrc` will do what sourcing a dotfile in bash usually does: it will run the script.  If you are setting `FOO=bar`, it will set the shell variable `FOO` to `bar`.  If you `export FOO` it will make that variable available in the current environment and the environment of any child processes *started by the same script*.